# Why install drivers if they came with the linux kernel

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, gpu

This morning, I wanted to show a friend of mine just how easy it has become to play video games on linux thanks to lutris. However during the installation of lutris, it asked me to download drivers for my graphics card. Now I have been told that most drivers for the GPU are already baked into the linux kernel(I have an AMD GPU)... so why does it ask me to install drivers for my graphics card if they already come baked into the linux kernel?

My second question is why was the installment of these drivers as simple as running a `pacman -S` command in the terminal? I mean since drivers are so low level and are loaded on OS startup, I would at least expect to have to download them from my manufacturers website and install them manually. Or at the very least have to restart my computer.

Comment: In computers over the years, they always require driver updates from time to time. Nothing new. Manufacturers try to make things as easy as possible for the user. Applies to Windows, Mac, and Linux.

Comment: What drivers exactly Lutris asked you to install?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I have been told that most drivers for the GPU are already baked into the linux kernel(I have an AMD GPU)... so why does it ask me to install drivers for my graphics card if they already come baked into the linux kernel?

Not all things called "drivers" are actually kernel drivers.

Some of them are just user-space libraries which work on top of what the kernel provides. For example, the entirety of OpenGL and Vulkan is implemented as libraries (libGL, etc), and on Linux those usually come from the Mesa project. The kernel driver knows *how* to talk to your AMDGPU, but Mesa knows *what* to say – the "drivers" provided by Mesa compile OpenGL shaders to GPU-specific instructions before uploading those through the kernel driver into the GPU.

So if you're installing something like `vulkan-radeon`, that's a driver – just not a kernel driver. You could say it's the "upper layer" of a driver, while the part that's in the kernel is the "lower layer".

Additionally, while there's only one type of kernel driver per system, the libraries (such as Mesa's) are loaded into each individual program and therefore have both 64-bit and 32-bit versions. You already have the 64-bit Mesa package, but if you want to run a 32-bit game through Wine then you need to also install the "lib32" package of the same libraries.

On Windows, all these pieces are directly provided by AMD, so they all come in the same installation bundle – if you install the "AMD drivers" you get both the kernel drivers *and* the OpenGL/DirectX libraries (of both 64-bit and 32-bit variants).

---

Also, as you observed, most, but *not all,* GPU drivers come with the kernel. NVIDIA is the biggest exception; they don't contribute any GPU support to the kernel, and their GPUs are much harder to write unofficial drivers for, too. (Unlike e.g. 'radeon' for old ATI, which was unofficial but still quite good.) The result is that kernel has relatively basic, unofficial drivers for NVIDIA cards, but you won't get much performance from them at all – you have to install their closed-source drivers for that.

> I mean since drivers are so low level and are loaded on OS startup, I would at least expect to have to download them from my manufacturers website and install them manually.

Those things actually have nothing to do with each other. Low-level components can be distributed the same way as high-level ones; in the end, they're just files. In fact on Windows you actually get most drivers through Windows Update. It's only the ones that *aren't* in Windows Update that you need to download from the manufacturer's website.

(Kernel drivers *can* be loaded dynamically; indeed most are. The kernel driver for USB sticks is loaded the first time you connect a USB stick, not on boot. You *do* need to reboot Linux in order to replace one kernel GPU driver with another, usually, though on Windows even that is no longer necessary.)

Answer (score 2):

The drivers that come 'baked into the linux kernel' are generally opensource drivers. These usually do not provide the best performance as they are not directly from the manufacturer. Thus for any graphics intensive activities, such as playing video games in your case, it is best to install proprietary drivers which do not come preinstalled. This is probably why Lutris prompts you to install these.

For your second question, you are partly right in saying the drivers are loaded on startup. They are essentially kernel modules, which are dynamically loaded into the kernel on startup. Thus, while it is simple to download and install them from the official repositories, you will need to restart your computer to be able to use them, as the opensource driver is the one loaded in your current instance

Comment: AMD graphics drivers are open/source -and- directly from the manufacturer. The `amdgpu-pro` proprietary overlay may give a slightly better performance for some tasks but not games. This has been thoroughly tested.